# Flask + SQLAlchemy + Google Ads API : How to properly update refresh token?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

```
# create/login local user on successful OAuth login
@oauth_authorized.connect_via(google)
def google_logged_in(blueprint, token):
    #
    # Token is accessible in this scope with token=xyz
    #
    # One Time Commit to unlock the database
    # db.session.commit()
    ##########################################

    if not token:
        flash("Failed to log in.", category="error")
        return False

    resp = blueprint.session.get("/oauth2/v1/userinfo")
    if not resp.ok:
        msg = "Failed to fetch user info."
        flash(msg, category="error")
        return False

    info = resp.json()
    user_id = str(info["id"])
    
    


    # Find this OAuth token in the database, or create it
    query = OAuth.query.filter_by(provider=blueprint.name, provider_user_id=user_id)
    try:
        oauth = query.one()
        db.session.commit()
    except NoResultFound:
        oauth = OAuth(provider=blueprint.name, provider_user_id=user_id, token=token)
    if oauth.user:
        # If this OAuth token already has an associated local account,
        # log in that local user account.
        # Note that if we just created this OAuth token, then it can't
        # have an associated local account yet.
        #

        try:
            update=OAuth.query.filter_by(provider=blueprint.name, provider_user_id=user_id)
            update.token=token
            db.session.commit()
        except:
            print('cannot update login token')
        
        login_user(oauth.user)
        flash("Successfully signed in.")

    else:
        # Create a new local user account for this user
        user = User(email=info["email"],image_url=info["picture"])
        # Associate the new local user account with the OAuth token
        oauth.user = user
        # Save and commit our database models
        db.session.add_all([user, oauth])
        db.session.commit()
        # Log in the new local user account
        login_user(user)
        flash("Successfully signed in.")

    # Disable Flask-Dance's default behavior for saving the OAuth token
    return False
```

What I am trying to do is following:

[Flowchart of my Process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzP1y.png)

I am database noob so i am not sure if I am doing what I want.

The problem is that my database locks after my token expires so something is not working with this part:

```
if oauth.user:
        # If this OAuth token already has an associated local account,
        # log in that local user account.
        # Note that if we just created this OAuth token, then it can't
        # have an associated local account yet.
        #

        try:
            update=OAuth.query.filter_by(provider=blueprint.name, provider_user_id=user_id)
            update.token=token
            db.session.commit()
        except:
            print('cannot update login token')

        login_user(oauth.user)
        flash("Successfully signed in.")
```

But I couldnt find out where the problem is.
Docs didnt help and following SO posts didnt help either:

[How do I unlock a SQLite database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151026/how-do-i-unlock-a-sqlite-database)

[SQLAlchemy and SQLite: database is locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895176/sqlalchemy-and-sqlite-database-is-locked)

https://www.reddit.com/r/flask/comments/36g2g7/af_sqlite_database_locking_problem/

Can someone get my ass out of existential chrisis and SQL dumbness?

Edit:
After the token has expired I now only get the message:
`oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors.InvalidGrantError: (invalid_grant) Token has been expired or revoked.`

I fixed a little bit when i replaced

`query = OAuth.query.filter_by(provider=blueprint.name, provider_user_id=user_id)`
with

`query = db.session.query(OAuth).filter_by(provider=blueprint.name, provider_user_id=user_id)`
but I seem not to write the new token to the database since I still get:
`oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors.InvalidGrantError: (invalid_grant) Token has been expired or revoked.`
So now my question how do I properly update refresh token?

Answer (score 0):

I did not catch an error in:

`update=db.session.query(OAuth).filter_by(provider=blueprint.name, provider_user_id=user_id) update.token=token`

because of try statement(i know its noobish). I than updated my code like this:

```
if oauth.user:
        # If this OAuth token already has an associated local account,
        # log in that local user account.
        # Note that if we just created this OAuth token, then it can't
        # have an associated local account yet.
        #

        #try:
        print('Trying to update the token')
        update=db.session.query(OAuth).filter_by(provider=blueprint.name, provider_user_id=user_id)
        update.token=token
        db.session.commit()
        print('User has been updated:', update.token==token)
        #except:
        #    print('cannot update login token')

        login_user(oauth.user)
        flash("Successfully signed in.")
```

Found out that
`AttributeError: 'BaseQuery' object has no attribute 'token'`

googled it quickly and found out that i need to use the first() like that:

`update=db.session.query(OAuth).filter_by(provider=blueprint.name, provider_user_id=user_id).first()`

Thanks to myself for being such noob and still get an answer to my question.